# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempt to use unsupported SchemaExport constructor accepting org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

Tags: hibernate, unsupported-class-version

How can I solve the following error?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempt to use unsupported SchemaExport constructor accepting org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration; one of the forms accepting org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataImplementor should be used instead
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:250)
    at com.slokam.model.CreativeMain.main(CreativeMain.java:21)
```

Comment: I have the same issue after upgrade from Hibernate 4 to 5. Did you find any solution?